# Setting a buffer/pointer to null

Tags: c++, pointers, buffer, fread

I am trying to constantly read data into a buffer of type unsigned char* from different files. However, I can't seem to set the buffer to NULL prior to reading in the next file.

Here is only the relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>


int
 main (int argc, char** argv) { 

     FILE* dataFile = fopen("C:\\File1.txt", "rb");
     unsigned char *buffer = NULL;
     buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(1000); 
     fread(buffer,1,1000,dataFile);
     fclose(dataFile);

     dataFile = fopen("C:\\File2.txt", "rb");
     buffer = NULL;
     fread(buffer,1,1000,dataFile);
     fclose(dataFile);

     system("pause");
     return 0; 

}
```

The error I run into is at the second occurrence of this line: **fread(buffer,1,1000,dataFile);**

The error I get is:

> Debug Assertion Failed! 
>   Expression: (buffer != NULL)

It points me to Line 147 of fread.c which is basically:

> ```
> /* validation */
> _VALIDATE_RETURN((buffer != NULL), EINVAL, 0);
> if (stream == NULL || num > (SIZE_MAX / elementSize))
> {
>     if (bufferSize != SIZE_MAX)
>     {
>         memset(buffer, _BUFFER_FILL_PATTERN, bufferSize);
>     }
>
>     _VALIDATE_RETURN((stream != NULL), EINVAL, 0);
>     _VALIDATE_RETURN(num <= (SIZE_MAX / elementSize), EINVAL, 0);
> }
> ```

I did Google for ways to get the buffer pointer to NULL and tried the various suggestions, but none seem to work. Anyone can clarify what is the right way to set it to NULL?

Comment: @KingsIndian Do you think `fstream` is a valid header in C, as you have tagged ?

Comment: @cnicutar If you are sure, it's c++ then you can edit so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `buffer` is a *pointer*.

When you do this:

```
buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(1000);
```

you allocate some space in memory, and assign its starting position to `buffer`. Remember, `buffer` holds the address of the beginning of the space, that's all. When you do this:

```
buffer = NULL;
```

you have thrown away that address.

**EDIT:**

C++ style, without dynamic memory:

```
#include <fstream>    
using std:: string;
using std:: ifstream;

void readFromFile(string fname)
{
  char buffer[1000];
  ifstream fin(fname.c_str());
  fin.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  // maybe do things with the data
}

int main ()
{
  readFromFile("File1.txt");
  readFromFile("File2.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

There's no need to erase the contents of the buffer. If the cost of allocating and deallocating the buffer with each call is too much, just add `static`:

```
  static char buffer[1000];
```

It will be overwritten each time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Beta. If I need to constantly call the fread to read into the buffer. How else would you recommend initializing it and then deleting its contents once it has been read?

Comment: @c0d3rz, 1) Do you want to use C or C++? 2) Do you have a reason to use dynamic memory? 3) When you say "delete", do you mean *erase the data*, or *free up the memory*?

Comment: (1) I want to use C++. (2) No, I don't need to use dynamic memory. (3) I mean erase the data. So that the data can be replaced by the next file.

Comment: Thank you VERY much Beta. Are there any negative performance effects of combining C and C++ code? Why do you suggest going to ifstread instead of fread?

Comment: @c0d3rz, I know of no performance effects of mixing C and C++. I know of no particular reason to use C++ over C in this case, but I like to use the C++ tools because they're generally safer and handier; e.g. once you get used to streaming, you'll never go back to `fprintf`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't say `buffer = NULL` because `fread` wil try to dereference it. Dereferencing `NULL` is one of the things that are certainly and completely illegal in C++. In effect you're losing what you got from `malloc`. Perhaps you're looking for `memset` and trying to zero the buffer:

```
memset(buffer, 0, 1000);
```

However, **you don't need to do** this before calling `fread`. There's simply no reason since `fread` will write the buffer anyway: it doesn't care if it's zeroed or not.

---

As a side note: you're writing very C-ish code in what I suspect is C++ (given your `fstream` header). There are better-suited I/O options for C++.

Comment: Hi cnicutar : Thanks for the reply. The above code is very simple. Actually, I have that in a function called readFromFile. I basically call this function everytime from my main program with just passing it a different filename. As you can imagine, it goes over the process everytime of creating the file object, the buffer and finally the read. What I notice is everytime, on the second read I get an error saying that buffer != NULL. Thus, I manually set it to NULL at the end of the function, so that when it is called again: I don't have the != NULL error.

Comment: Can you please give me a pointer on the better I/O code for C++? I'd appreciate it ...

Comment: @c0d3rz Just look into iostreams :-)

Comment: I find this quite usefull: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html